# Renew Azure CosmosDB MasterKey with Service Principal

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I cannot find any documentation on how to generate/renew the masterkey of CosmosDB for Read/Write or only for Read.

I can do it on Azure Portal, but I wish to do this with python or with a REST API.

For lot of ressource in Azure, we can use the Service Principal to generate a Token and then access other API. Like in Databricks.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \ 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token \
-d 'client_id=${CLIENT_ID}' \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
-d 'scope=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d%2F.default' \
-d 'client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}'
```

With the `scope=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d%2F.default` it will grant me access to Databricks API. `https://vault.azure.net/.default` is for Azure KeyVault. But I can't find anything for cosmos-DB

Any Idea on how to manage cosmosdb from a Service Principal?

Comment: I found out I can use `ClientSecretCredential` from `azure.identity` python's SDK to get an `aad_credentials` with the Service Principal, and then connect to  `CosmosClient` from `azure-cosmos`'s python SDK. But I'm still curious on the feasibility of my question. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/samples/access_cosmos_with_aad.py#L70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this using the Python Azure Management Library for Cosmos DB.

Pip install these

```
azure-identity
azure-mgmt-resource==15.0.0
azure-mgmt-cosmosdb==6.4.0
azure-cosmos==4.2.0
```

Some samples that show you how to get started using this library [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-python-management/blob/main/samples/cosmosdb/manage_database_account.py)

The API article on how to regenerate a key is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-cosmosdb/azure.mgmt.cosmosdb.operations.databaseaccountsoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-cosmosdb-operations-databaseaccountsoperations-begin-regenerate-key)

Comment: Indeed, I used this solution https://github.com/microsoft/AzureTRE/issues/345#issuecomment-894959647. But I'm still sad that CosmosDB is not able to generate tempoary tokens for a single user.

Comment: It does. You'll have to do via rest. Can learn more here. https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data?tabs=using-primary-key#resource-tokens